# Jupyter R Plotly 404 error with sample code

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I tried to run the Plotly R Chart in Jupyter  from [here](https://plot.ly/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks/#install-python) and get:

> 404 Not Found error.

the code is as follows

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rchisq(1000, df = 1, ncp = 0)
group <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 1000, replace = T)
size <- sample(1:5, size = 1000, replace = T)

ds <- data.frame(x, y, group, size)

p <- plot_ly(ds, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers", group = group, size = size) %>%
  layout(title = "Scatter Plot")
embed_notebook(p,file="/Jupyter Notebooks/plotlyJupyterHTML/test3.html")
```

The terminal has an error message:

> 404 GET /Jupyter%20Notebooks/plotlyJupyterHTML/test3.html.embed (::1)     6.51ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Plotly%20%in%20R%20Testing-Copy1-ipynd

There is a file in the directory `D:\Jupyter Notebooks\plotlyJupyterHTML\test3.html` but not one with the additional extension `.embed`.

The html file has the data and creates the correct chart when opened in firefox.

It seems the GET statement may have the wrong file name but I would appreciate any insight to get this to work.

Here is the session info:

```
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------
Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 system   i386, mingw32               
 ui       RTerm                       
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2016-07-11                  



package     * version date       source                             
 assertthat    0.1     2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 base64enc     0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                     
 colorspace    1.2-6   2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 devtools      1.12.0  2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 digest        0.6.9   2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 evaluate      0.9     2016-04-29 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 ggplot2     * 2.1.0   2016-03-01 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 gridExtra     2.2.1   2016-02-29 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 gtable        0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 htmltools     0.3.5   2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 htmlwidgets   0.6     2016-02-25 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 httr          1.2.1   2016-07-03 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 IRdisplay     0.4.1   2016-07-09 Github (IRkernel/IRdisplay@8e24901)
 IRkernel      0.6     2016-07-09 Github (IRkernel/IRkernel@8cdfe5e) 
 jsonlite      1.0     2016-07-01 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 memoise       1.0.0   2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 munsell       0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 pbdZMQ        0.2-3   2016-05-20 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 plotly      * 3.6.0   2016-05-18 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 plyr          1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 R6            2.1.2   2016-01-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 Rcpp          0.12.5  2016-05-14 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 repr          0.7     2016-05-13 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 scales        0.4.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 stringi       1.1.1   2016-05-27 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                     
 stringr       1.0.0   2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 tibble        1.1     2016-07-04 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 tidyr         0.5.1   2016-06-14 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 uuid          0.1-2   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                     
 viridis       0.3.4   2016-03-12 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 withr         1.0.2   2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                     
 yaml          2.1.13  2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in MacOS.
This is the workaround I did,

```
p <- plot_ly(ds, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers", group = group, size = size)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), "index.html")
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("index.html"), collapse="\n")
display_html(rawHTML)
```

This is not the best solution, but for the time being this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of that, probably:
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/e80095358c19ef3032b611bd3a342504a163705a

It has been fixed already here:
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/86e1e3607d58b3af2cf1c809f71c2536ce20a87d

You could wait, until it gets released to CRAN, or install developement version from github:

```
 devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```

or

```
 git clone https://github.com/ropensci/plotly
 R CMD INSTALL plotly
```